# How can slot 1 of the Apple ][ replace the keyboard?

Tags: apple-ii

[Nick Westgate](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/users/71/nick-westgate) posted a comment a few years back on [a question about how slot 7 was unique](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/1312/what-makes-slot-7-of-the-apple-unique-from-1-6-and-how-was-this-used) stating that "Slot 1 on the //e is also unique - it can be used to replace the keyboard".

What was it about slot 1 on the //e that it could do this? How and was it ever implemented? Was it only the //e or did the earlier ]['s or perhaps later IIgs support this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From Sather's [Understanding the Apple IIe](https://archive.org/details/Understanding_the_Apple_IIe) on page 7-19, at the top of column 2:

> Slot 1 has two signals connected which are not available at the other
>   slots, ENKBD' and CLKEN'. These are present primarily for diagnostic
>   and testing purposes, but innovative peripheral card designs could
>   make good use of them. When ENKBD' is high, the keyboard ROM is
>   inhibited and the other devices can place data on MD0-6 of the data
>   bus when read access is made to $C000—$C01F. When the CLKEN' is high,
>   the motherboard 14M signal is disabled, and a card in the auxiliary
>   slot can inject an alternate master clockpulse reference onto the 14M
>   line. If, as normally is the case, ENKBD' and CLKEN' are not connected
>   on the Slot 1 card, motherboard pull-down resistors pull these lines
>   low so the affected circuits can function normally.

The advantage of keyboards interfaced via ENKBD in slot 1 is that they would be compatible with software that directly accessed the soft-switches instead of using the firmware routines.

Many 3rd-party keyboards existed, but I can't confirm if any used ENKBD. Here's a long [list of disability keyboards](https://www.tifaq.org/archive/disability_keyboards.txt) with around 30 supporting the Apple II family, but none exclusive to the //e.

The name "Concept Keyboard" was familiar to me, and there are some [references to it using a large interface card](https://www.applefritter.com/content/apple-mkiii-interface-card), but it's listed as being also compatible with the Apple //c and IIgs, even though according to the Hardware Reference manual the IIgs didn't retain ENKBD in slot 1. The [Concept A3 model](http://www.computinghistory.org.uk/det/6999/Microterminals-Concept-A3-256-tablet-keyboard/) appeared to use a much smaller card that doesn't use pin 35 which carried ENKBD on the //e.

Comment: Can verify this was done!   It didn’t need special-purpose hardware, either. In 1980 my father acquired a surplus DECwriter LA36 terminal (serial printer with keyboard, no monitor) and connected it to slot 1 of our Apple II (48k). Typing `PR#1` would cause the printer to start echoing the command line, while typing `IN#1` would allow the keyboard on the DEC printer to type commands instead of the Apple built-in keyboard.

Comment: @whiskeychief interesting note, but are you sure that it wasn't simply using the redirection of CIN as a result of the IN#1 statement? Any card could take over standard input to the Apple II console with an IN#x statement, including the Super Serial Card which may have been the interface card your father used. Non-character I/O cards (such as disk controller) didn't implement the feature, naturally, and instead would just cause a "boot from disk" operation to occur.

Comment: @bjb Actually, non-character cards such as the disk controller _did_ take over CIN at times: this was how you'd do text file I/O in BASIC. DOS always had COUT hooked and when it saw a Ctrl-D (`CHR$(4)`) followed by `READ MYFILE` would take over CIN so that `INPUT A$` would read data from the disk file.